# change page title with jquery, without incrementing to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to update the page title a user is on, to add in their current notification count (like facebook does)

I have this:

```
var current_page_title = $(document).find("title").text();
document.title = '(' + data.title_total + ') ' + current_page_title;
```

The problem is, it keeps doing this:
"(12) (12) page title" - it adds the bracket number each time.

Is there a way to always use the original title, not the new one that already has the brackets?

Comment: you either store what is in the original or write a regular expression to remove the part you do not want....

Answer (score 4):

You can save the original value of title outside the code block where you change it and then just append to it.

```
var pageTitle;

var current_page_title = document.title
                     //  ^ btw, no need for $(document).find("title").text() here
if ( !pageTitle ) { pageTitle = current_page_title; }
document.title = '(' + data.title_total + ') ' + pageTitle;
```

Answer (score 3):

`document.title = '(' + data.title_total + ')' + document.title.replace(/\(*\)/, '');`

edited with @serdar.sanri's answer to work for first time

Comment: posted before I finished mine. short and neat answer.

Comment: `document.title = '(' + data.title_total + ')' + document.title.replace(/\(\d+\)+\s/, '');`

Answer (score 1):

Look this example, i using regex to get the value in brackets.
Try to do it with the title.

https://jsfiddle.net/dsgyjs8m/1/

```
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="(12) lorem ipsum" />
<input type="text" name="newTitle" id="newTitle" value="" />

$(function(){
  var value    = $("#title").val();
  var newValue = value.replace(/([\[(])(.+?)([\])])/g, replacer);

    $("#newTitle").val(newValue);
});

function replacer(match, v1, v2, v3, offset, string) {
  return v1 + (1+parseInt(v2)) + v3;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Just reformulate it every time. Don't blindly append to the current title.

You could cache the current title and append do that.

```
var title = document.title;

// later
document.title = ... + title;
```

Comment: I have no idea what page they will be on, I don't want to have to write JS code for every single page title, i want to use the current title ;)